# How to change datasource for different segmented control index

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I am using a segmented control with titles, phone and email. I am fetching the contacts details from addressbook and storing them as array of dictionaries. Each dictionary is with keys "name", "email", "image", "phone". My requirement is to show only contacts with emails in tableview when email is tapped and show contacts with phones when phone button is tapped on segment control. Please help me to achieve this.

Comment: you were store teh all dictionary in single array. at the same time show your segment control action , it is easy to resolve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can implement this multiple ways.in here I use the `Tag` Concept , for example

**Step-1**

in your `ViewDidLoad`, set as your `tableview.tag=1;`

**Step-2**

```
- (IBAction)segBtnTapped:(id)sender {

  if(yourSegmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex==0){
    // email
    tableview.tag=1;
 }
 else if(segControlForColor.selectedSegmentIndex==1){
   // phone
    tableview.tag=2;
 }
else{
    // titles
    tableview.tag=3;
 }
 [yourtableView reloadData];
}
```

**Step-3**

no need to change on numberof rows in section or anything just call in your `CellForRowatIndexpath` and `didSelectrowatIndexpath`, for ex

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

   if(tableview.tag == 1)
  {
      //code for email  
      cell.textLabel.text =[[yourarrayName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"email"];

  }

  else if(tableview.tag == 2)
  {
      //code for phone

cell.textLabel.text =[[yourarrayName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"phone"];

  }

  else if(tableview.tag == 3)
  {
      //code for titles 
         cell.textLabel.text =[[yourarrayName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"titles"];
  }
  return cell;
}

 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 if(tableview.tag == 1)
  {
      //code for email  
        NSLog(@"email==%@",[[yourarrayName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"email"]);

  }

  else if(tableview.tag == 2)
  {
      //code for phone

    NSLog(@"phone==%@",[[yourarrayName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"phone"]);

  }

  else if(tableview.tag == 3)
  {

         NSLog(@"title==%@",[[yourarrayName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"titles"]);
  }

}
```

Comment: Nice. But in the above code, I can display Phone numbers and emails directly in the tableview, but I want to show the contact names with emails once and contact names with phone numbers next time .

Comment: we can modify whatever we need chioce is yours

Comment: Resolved ... I used for in loop to iterate through the array

Comment: @Naveen -- happy to hear  bro. if my answer is useful give the upvote for the answer , it is useful in future

Comment: Hi, I am having another issue. I want to get my navigation controller title in this format Invite(3/50), 3 is number of tableview rows I selected and 50 is constant. Please help

Comment: simple do like   self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Invite(%d/50)",yourarrayname.count];

Comment: Hi, When I select the each row in tableview the arraycount should increase by 1. but currently for mutliple rows I am selecting the count is always 1.

Comment: naveen -- pardon can you explain more

Comment: -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    FFContactInviteCell *contactCell = (FFContactInviteCell *) [self.contactsTableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    contactCell.contactNameLabel.textColor = [UIColor tabBarTitleBlueColor];
    self.selectedContactsList = [self.contactsTableview indexPathsForSelectedRows];
    self.title =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Invite(%lu/50)",(unsigned long)self.selectedContactsList.count];
}

Comment: My navigation bar title (0/50), numerator should increase everytime I select a row in a tableview

Comment: are you allocate the memory for this `self.selectedContactsList ` at the same time you were assigned to array , that the reason you get only one value,

Comment: I am allocating it in viewDidLoad

Comment: then you need to **addobject**

Comment: When I am tapping on the cell it is selecting multiple times, like I am tapping  on first cell 7 times, count is increased to 7. But it should be limited to 1 for each cell.

Comment: then you need to create the one , see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23727255/multiple-checkmark-when-row-selected-in-uitableview-ios

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by just checking the segmentedControl index state in the below delegate method.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        // Load phone values from dictionary 
        ....
     }
    else {
        // Load email values from dictionary
        ....
    }
}
```

Don't forget to reload table when segmented control index gets changed.

Comment: I can do this, but my dictionary is having values for keys "name", "email", "phone". In one case I want to show contacts having email and in next i need to show contacts with phone numbers. How can I separate them.

Comment: Traverse through the array of dictionary and use value of "phone" key for selectedsegmentindex 0